# Phrasal verb - stamp something out (definition)

Tags: usage, phrasal-verbs, definition

I have read [this](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-china-health-xi-economy/xi-warned-officials-that-efforts-to-stop-virus-could-hurt-economy-sources-idUSKBN2050JL), and I read "and **stamping out an epidemic** that has killed more than 1,000 people and infected more than 40,000."

So, from Cambridge Dictionary I get:

> **stamp something out**
>
> — phrasal verb
>
> to stop or destroy something:
>
> [Source](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/es/diccionario/ingles/stamp-something-out)

After read the definition the text makes sense to me which is perfect but... if I isolate those words and look for "stamp" and "out" the text above does not make sense to me. So, I conclude that a phrasal verb is not linked with their isolated words. **How is it possible?** (I do not if I am right or not).

Comment: This sense of **stamp out** is perhaps not *entirely* unrelated to their individual literal meanings.  You can quite literally stamp out a fire.  Generally, though, yes English phrasal verbs are *semantic units [which] cannot be understood based upon the meanings of the individual parts but must be taken as a whole. In other words, the meaning is non-compositional and thus unpredictable* (from Wikipedia).

Comment: Means stopping the epidemic